# Post back values without clearing page

Tags: asp.net, html, forms, post, razor

Note: I've been using ASP.NET Webforms, so ViewState was my friend.

Note: Default.html and Default.cshtml are two different files/pages.

Basically, all I'm trying to do is take form values from a .html page, post them, and then go back to the original page without the values resetting.

Here's what I have so far:

My client-side script

```
<!-- Default.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Testing Stuff</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="mainpage" action="Default.cshtml" method="post">
        <div style="clear:both;" id="dbInput">
            <label for="linedesc">Description:</label>&nbsp;
            <input type="text" id="linedesc" name="linedesc" />
            <br /><br />
            <input id="fruits" name="options1" value="fruits" type="radio" />
            <label for="fruits">Fruits</label>&nbsp;
            <input id="candies" name="options1" value="candies" type="radio" />
            <label for="candies">Candies</label>&nbsp;
            <input id="snacks" name="options1" value="snacks" type="radio" />
            <label for="snacks">Snacks</label>
            <br /><br />
            <label for="options2">Choose beverage:</label>&nbsp;
             <select id="options2" name="options2">
                <option value="Coca-Cola">Coca-Cola</option>
                <option value="Sprite">Sprite</option>
                <option value="Root Beer">Root Beer</option>
                <option value="Orange Juice">Orange Juice</option>
            </select>
            <br /><br />
            <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And my server-side script

```
//Default.cshtml
@{
    var linedesc = Request.Form["linedesc"];
    var food = Request.Form["options1"];
    var drinks = Request.Form["options2"];

    // Go back to Default.html and keep values selected, ie. values don't reset
    var blah = "hi";
}
```

All I want to do is simple, no bells, no whistles, postback and return. I'm just missing that last piece.

Comment: Do you post on the same page ? eg, on top says `Default.html`, on action says: `Default.cshtml`

Comment: No, those are two different pages. It would like Index.html and Index.php.

Comment: Is there any reason you need to refresh the html page?  If not, you can use a javascript ajax request to send the data to your server, get a response, and the original html page stays just as it is.

Comment: Learning purposes. Is there not a way to do this without ajax?